# Translation of "I couldn't care less"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What would be the closest translation to the sentence "I couldn't care less."

It is similar in meaning to

> Es ist mir egal.
>
> (It doesn't matter to me)

but I think it's not quite the same. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think

> Das *kümmert* mich (überhaupt) nicht.

is even stronger than thekeyofgb’s *"Das ist mir (völlig) egal."* because it emphasizes that no thoughts will be spend on something while *egal* can just mean some (passive) half-heartedness.

In an informal context *I couldn't care less* can also be translated with *„Das geht mir am Arsch vorbei!“* or *„Darauf scheiße ich!“* but this is *extremely* rude.

Comment: Even if "Das geht mir am Arsch vorbei!" is somewhat rude it hits the nail onto it's head!

Answer (score 7):

I'd say

> Das ist mir völlig egal

It's stronger than

> Das ist mir egal

As "I couldn't care less"  is stronger than "I don't care"

Comment: Oder "Das ist mir völlig gleichgültig"

Comment: @Em1 Das wäre nicht so toll. Gleichgültigkeit ist eine Eigenschaft der Person, nicht des Gegenstands.

Comment: @Toscho Welcher Gegenstand? Ach was soll's. *Ist mir schnuppe*.

Comment: @Em1 Der Gegenstand der Egalheit.

Answer (score 3):

As you have correctly stated:

> Es ist mir egal. = It doesn't matter to me.

But the sentence can have other translations:

> Es ist mir egal. = I don't mind.
>
> Es ist mir egal. = I don't care.

If you want to increase the proposition `I don't care.` by `I couldn't care less.`, you have in general two possibilities:

1. `Es ist mir [Wortgruppe] egal.` / `Es ist mir [Wort]egal.` e.g.

   - `scheißegal`
   - `pupsegal`
   - `total egal`
   - `sowas von egal`
2. Other phrases:

   - `Das kümmert mich nicht im geringsten.` (Probably the most literal translation.)
   - `Darauf pfeife ich.`
   - `Das tangiert mich (nicht mal) peripher.`

Comment: bei *sowas von egal* muss man irgendwelche Geste machen? und ist nicht *pfeiffen* mit nur einem *f*? Dann wäre meine Antwort falsch.

Comment: @c.p. `pfeifen` hab ich geändert. Bei `sowas von egal` kann man natürlich Gesten machen, man kann es aber auch lassen.

Answer (score 3):

In certain parts of the country you'll hear:

> Ist mir (doch) (völlig) Wurscht!

where "Wurscht" (or even "Worscht") is how one pronounces "Wurst" there.

This is less gentle than "egal", but not as rude as mentioning "Arsch" or "Scheiße".

Comment: +1 for adding "doch" - this is super idiomatic.

Comment: In northern Germany is written and pronounced as "ist mir wurst". And "wurst" and "wurscht" are both written in small letters. See my answer in: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34797/das-ist-mir-wurst-etymologie-bedeutung?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Almost just a side note but important enough to know as you may encounter it.

The sentence

> Das ist mir egal

is often modified in a way that *egal* is replaced with a couple of words which actually do not make any sense:

> Das ist mir Schnuppe.
>   Das ist mir Latte.
>   Das ist mir Wurst.

These three are possibly the most common ones, at least I've encountered any of them several times. But you can place almost anything there. There's even a Facebook group called:

> Das ist mir sowas von Hans Sarpei.

<sub>Note, this is the name of a football player.</sub>

The form "sowas von" is some kind of emphasis, like *völlig* or *absolut*.

Eventually, as it hasen't been said yet, something can be *piep(s) egal*.

> Das ist mir sowas von schnurzpiep(s)egal.

Comment: +1 für *schnurzpiepsegal* \o/

Answer (score 0):

Nicht so elegant, aber auch praktisch, wäre

> Ist mir scheißegal.
>
> Mir ist (Etw) scheißegal.

Du kannst auch

> Auf (Etw.Akk) pfeife ich!

sagen.

> *Z.B. Auf den Tod pfeife ich*

Answer (score 0):

> Das ist mir total schnurz.

I am not sure if this expression is outmoded, but I heard it in a speaking book, liked it, and added it to my vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Jugendliche würden den Satz als "Wayne" übersetzen:

> A: bla bla bla
>
> B: *ring ring* (ahmt Telefonläuten nach) Was? Wer? *reicht sein Telefon an A* Hier für dich. Wayne.

denn Wayne interessiert's:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Um eine bekannte Deutsche Band zu zitieren:

> Es könnte mir nicht egaler sein.

*Die Ärzte - Ignorama*

Answer (score -3):

> Es tangiert mich peripher.

Wheras he means his butt. He doesn't give a shit. Or even a single fart. (pupsegal) (protip: schnurzpiepegal)

and somehow can be even latte(idontevenknowwhy).

Comment: Das sagte mal jemand, der originell sein wollte und es auch war, und dann haben es 1000e wiederholt, die natürlich kaum noch originell waren. Insofern ist es nur in wenigen Situationen als Übersetzung passend und kaum die, die dem engl. Original am nähesten kommt.