# Is it "egal bei jemandem" or "egal für jemanden"?

Tags: word-usage

What is right way to say "It doesn't matter to me" in German?
Is it *Egal bei mir* or *Egal für mich*, or are both of them correct answers?

Comment: *Egal bei mir* is wrong, *egal für mich* is somehow right but sounds strange. You are probably looking for *ist mir egal*.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/egal_gleich_einerlei#Bedeutung2

Comment: Related questions: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9090/1224 – http://german.stackexchange.com/q/12357/1224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Egal bei mir" is wrong and "Egal für mich" sounds really strange.

In German, you would say "[Das/Es] Ist mir egal" or "Das interessiert mich nicht".